# Does Java Instrumentation Agent support New Method Definition in a class?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I reloaded on of my test application classes using `Instrumentation#redefineClasses(ClassDefinition)` method. When I tried adding a new method in the class file and call it from an existing method. It was not happy to for me to do so. But when I called some existing method and other Java Built-In Library methods, it was working fine.

My question is - Is this limitation known/acknowledged by Oracle or Open JDK implementations? I suspect even if you can redefine/retransform your classes using INstrumentation Manifest.MF file - there must be somre sort of limitations to how far you can go with it.

Does anyone have any experience in this thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-):

> The redefinition may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes. The redefinition **must not add, remove or rename fields or methods**, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance. These restrictions maybe be lifted in future versions. The class file bytes are not checked, verified and installed until after the transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in error this method will throw an exception.

So the answer would be no, it's not possible.

Comment: For the record : commercial tools such as JRebel handle such changes easily.

Comment: @GhostCat That's true but they are using a native agent and this is not what the question was about.

Comment: It is more to complete the picture. You never know what future readers might be looking for.

Comment: The same limitation applies to native agents and JRebel is far from achieving this easily, it is a lot of work which makes the tool unsuitable for production. As a matter of fact, the JRebel agent must be applied at startup to build a facade around all user classes to make them redefinable.

Comment: Clearly I was sleeping when that came on the screen. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: JRebel actually shows you how to write the instrumentation agent. So no losses there

Comment: I think, it’s fair to state that adding methods is not possible through this API. You can work-around this by converting every class to a facade but then, you are still not adding methods through this API, you’re implementing this feature atop your own method dispatch implementation. If you call that “it’s possible” then almost everything becomes possible as you can always load a new software (your own JVM or whatever) that pretends to do what you intent into the process…